How does SKLearn derive LASSO coefficients?
I am trying to derive SKLearn's LASSO coefficients using SciPy optimize, just to get an idea of how SKLearn is working under the hood. However, I cannot get the parameters to match.
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data[:,0:3], iris.data[:,3]

lasso_reg = Lasso(alpha=1)
lasso_reg.fit(X, y)

Gives lasso_reg.coef_ =  array([ 0.        , -0.        ,  0.09270611]) and lasso_reg.intercept_ = 0.8509437849691903
When I try to derive these myself I am trying to minimize:
def lasso_min(params):
    return sum((y  - params[0] - np.matmul(X, params[1:]))**2) + lam * sum([abs(val) for val in params[1:]])

Using:
lam = 1
from scipy import optimize
sol = optimize.minimize(lasso_min, [0,0,0,0])

This gives me sol.x = array([-0.29598937, -0.14396059,  0.16120468,  0.49060031])
Even when I increase the value of lam, I cannot manage to regularize the coefficients to 0. Could someone explain what I am doing wrong here? I assume its something pretty basic in my code and not a deeper lack of understanding?
Many thanks.

A few things might be wrong here:

First, LASSO does not use any of the default optimizers from scipy.  It uses coordinate descent, which is actually pretty simple.
Second, you don't seem to scale your inputs, which is pretty important for LASSO.

Here is a simple script to fit LASSO via coordinate descent.  I get the same coefficients as sklearn.  Note I do not need the loss defined here since the soft thresholding update w[j] = soft_thresh(beta + 1/N * x@r) is obtained from the loss exactly -- no need for a (sub)gradient calculation of a loss evaluation.
I wrote this code using instructions from "Statistical Learning with Sparsity: The Lasso and Generalizations" by Hastie, Tibshirani, and Wainwright.
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris



iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data[:,0:3], iris.data[:,3]
X  = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

lasso_reg = Lasso(alpha=0.1)
lasso_reg.fit(X, y)

# Print the intercept and coefficient.
print(lasso_reg.intercept_, lasso_reg.coef_)

## How sklearn does it
# Add a column of 1s so the intercept is applied.
lX = np.c_[np.ones(y.size), X]

def soft_thresh(x, lam = 0.1):

    kern = np.abs(x) - lam
    return np.sign(x) * np.where(kern>0, kern, 0)

num_iters = 100
w = np.zeros(lX.shape[1])
w[0] = np.mean(y)
N = len(y)

for i in range(num_iters):
    for j in range(1, w.size):
        beta = w[j]
        r = y - lX@w
        x = lX[:, j]
        w[j] = soft_thresh(beta + 1/N * x@r)


print(w)
```


Thanks, that makes sense. The scaling was an obvious error. I still don't get match the answers when I use the Sci Py optimizer. I am still a bit confused why a more complex optimizer from Sci Py wouldn't reach the same answer as co-ordinate descent. Again I imagine it is something wrong with my loss function...

@AdamS I anticipate the reason is because the solution lays on a corner of the polytope which defines the constraint region.  Since the loss is not differentiable at that point, gradient based optimizers are maybe "stepping over" the optima.  Are you getting non-zero estimates from the optimizer?

Yes, exactly. I'm getting close to 0 but not exact. That makes sense! Thanks a lot.
